# How do I retrieve certain information from database using the ID of the table to extract certain information?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am currently doing a small web project and am struggling to get individual names from the database to appear in different panels of my website. There are 18 different names in the table I need and I need to display them in 18 individual panels as shown here [Screenshot of Panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCe8t.png).

I am using MvC and have this SQL statement in my model -

```
public function fetchMonarch($Monarch, $MonarchID)
 {
     $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM monarchy WHERE Monarch = '" . $Monarch ."'AND MonarchID = '".$MonarchID."'";

     $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); //Prepare PDO statement
     $statement->execute(); //Executes PDO statement

     $dataSet = [];
     while ($row = $statement->fetch()) { //Fetches the next row matching the query
         $dataSet[] = new LoginData($row);
     }

     return $dataSet;
 }
```

How would I set it up in my controller so that I can access the names I want to in each panel using Session ?

Any ideas of how to do this even if you think I maybe going about this incorrectly would be a massive help as I have hit a snag.

This is my panel code within the HTML -

```html
<div id="monarch1">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Title</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Panel content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div id="monarch2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Panel content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: It is unclear from your question, whether you don't know how to get the information from database of how to display it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you are after is something like this:

```
$dataSet = [];
while ($row = $statement->fetch()) { //Fetches the next row matching the query
    $dataSet[$row['MonarchID'] = new LoginData($row); // note the ID
}
```

Then within your HTML:

```
foreach ($dataSet as $id=>$monarch){
    echo '<div id="monarch2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">'.$monarch->objectData.'</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            '.$monarch->objectData.'
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>';
}
```

$monarch->objectData would reference your keys in LoginData($row) or alternatively store a new key in $allData['MonarchID'] = $row; and then foreach on $alldata and instead of $monarch->objectData you would use $monarch['FieldInfo'].

If you need to specifically place your elements - use ordering in the SQL or alternatively you can access $dataSet['MonarchID']->objectData to place your content in specific places.

Comment: Great - if it is please make it the answer :o)